# Mongoose: Binary subtype 4 to string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have query on my mongo that is returning an UUID as a Bin4. How do I convert it to a string?

```
Binary {
  _bsontype: 'Binary',
  sub_type: 4,
  position: 16,
  buffer: <Buffer 93 02 fc 42 a9 6b 47 7b ab 63 5c 78 c1 07 3a 2c> }
```

What I am expecting as return is something like this `9302FC42-A96B-477B-AB63-5C78C1073A2C`

I've tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userData._id))` and what I get is this `kwL8QqlrR3urY1x4wQc6LA==`

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

you may try : print(BinData(4, "kwL8QqlrR3urY1x4wQc6LA=="));

you will get output as UUID("9302fc42-a96b-477b-ab63-5c78c1073a2c")
which you may convert to string like:

```
var x = BinData(4, "kwL8QqlrR3urY1x4wQc6LA==");

function ToUUID(hex) {
    var a =  hex.substr(0, 2) + hex.substr(2, 2)  + hex.substr(4, 2) + hex.substr(6, 2);
    var b =  hex.substr(8, 2) + hex.substr(10, 2);
    var c =  hex.substr(12, 2) + hex.substr(14, 2);
    var d = hex.substr(16, 16);
    hex = a + b + c + d;
    var uuid = hex.substr(0, 8) + '-' + hex.substr(8, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(12, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(16, 4) + '-' + hex.substr(20, 12);
    return '"' + uuid + '"';
}

var z = ToUUID(x.hex());
print(z);
```